# foreach printing array elements

Tags: perl

I'm trying to loop through multiple array elements, and based on the array, I'm trying print each element with its corresponding value.

```
@_disk = ('0:0','0:1');
@_diskStatus= ('OK','Critical');
```

Here is what I have tried.  I'm not sure how to use conditions to get the desired output:

```
foreach (@_diskID, @_diskStatus)
{
    # Print the data in JSON
    print "\t,\n" if not $_first;
    $_first = 0;

    print "\t{\n";
    print "\t\t\"{#DISKID}\":\"$_\"\n";
    print "\n\t}\n";
}

print "\n\t]\n";
print "}\n";
```

Desired output

```
 {
        "data":[

        {
            "{#DISKID}":" 0:0"

        }
        ,
        {
            "{#STATUS}":" Ok"

        }
        ,
        {
            "{#DISKID}":" 0:1"

        }
        ,
        {
            "{#STATUS}":" Critical"

        }

        ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both arrays are always the same size, it would be simpler to loop through the indexes of the array than the actual elements.

```
# only need one array here because they are the same size
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#_diskID ) { 
   ...
}
```

Also there is no need to build up a JSON string like this in Perl, there is a nice module on CPAN called [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) which can create them for your from a hash.

So, knowing this you can simply create a hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @_disk = ('0:0','0:1');
my @_diskStatus= ('OK','Critical');

my %json_hash = ( data => [] );
foreach my $i ( 0 .. $#_disk ) {
   push @{$json_hash{data}},
      { '{#DISKID}' => $_disk[$i],
        '{#STATUS}' => $_diskStatus[$i],
      };
}

my $json_string = encode_json \%json_hash;
print "$json_string\n";

# prints
# {"data":[{"{#STATUS}":"OK","{#DISKID}":"0:0"},{"{#DISKID}":"0:1","{#STATUS}":"Critical"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays have the same number of elements:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @_disk = ('0:0','0:1');
my @_diskStatus = ('OK','Critical');

for my $i (0 .. $#_disk) {
    print "$_disk[$i] $_diskStatus[$i]\n";
}
```